# Как сделать с помощью промиса так, чтобы вывелось сначала 1 а потом 2 в консоле?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(2);

setTimeout(() => {
 console.log(1)
}, 2000);
```

Comment: перенеси 2 под 1

Comment: Нужно как-то с помощью промисов сделать

Comment: отлично. прочитайте про промисы, сделайте

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да что-то не могу уловить промис

Comment: в гугле по слову "промисы" первые 4-5 ссылок - всё очень подробно расписывают. Углубляться даже пока сильно не надо. Просто потратить немного времени и понять. Это не так сложно как кажется.

Comment: https://itchief.ru/javascript/promise - здесь так вообще в шапке код, который вам нужен

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про работу eventLoop в браузере и ответите сами себе на вопрос.
Первый вызов попадает в основной стэк, в то время как setTimeout() помещается в callback queue
И только после того как стэк очистится от выполнения, туда начнут попадать инструкции из callback queue.

Поэтому даже если вы укажете 0ms во времени исполнения setTimeout() - он вс
ё равно попадает в очередь и будет ждать опустошения стека

Так что, есть вариант использовать промисы, либо аналогичным образом первый вызов обернуть в setTimeout();